# What PKCS standard is this?

Tags: rsa, pkcs8

What PKCS standard is the public key in the image below?  It seems to me that it is PKCS#8, but what I've read makes me think that PKCS#8 only applies to private keys.

[image]

Here is the corresponding private key which is PKCS#8.  Note they look identical except the private key only contains modulus and exponent info.

[image]

Comment: Found my answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27913/why-can-ssh-keygen-export-a-public-key-in-pem-pkcs8-format). Short story, the structure and contents of an SPKI public key and a PKCS#8 private key are identical except the public key lacks the private parts. Said another way, the public key only has the exponent and modulus.

Comment: Also SPKI wraps the algorithm-dependent part in BITSTRING while PKCS8 wraps it in OCTETSTRING. (Similarly the the algorithm-dependent signature in X.509/PKIX is wrapped by BITSTRING, as is the optional publickey in rfc5958, but the encrypted content in PKCS8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo and all contents in PKCS7/CMS are  OCTETSTRING. OTOH _extensions_ in X.509/PKIX, and some other things that derive from or copy it, use OID + OCTETSTRING.)

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for that note, I had overlooked that.  Another difference that I missed the first time is that the PKCS#8 structure also has a `version` element in the first sequence, but the X.509 SPKI does not.